How do I stop AOE2:HD AI from resigning?
I want to stop the Age of Empires II: HD Edition AI from resigning too early. According to the AOE forums,

To permanently disable AI resign you can do the following:

Right click the game in Steam library → Browse local files

Go to resources\_common\ai\Promisory and open customConstants.per in notepad

On the third line, change (defconst enable-resign 1) to (defconst enable-resign 0)


This will affect your singleplayer, and MP games created as a host, though not MP games joined as a client.

However, this is for AOE2:DE—I don't have this file because I'm playing AOE2:HD (I know it's been retired because of DE). Is there a way to effect this change for my version?

I know you can issue a chat command that stops resigning "104: Don't Resign". Source : https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1912881515
From what i've read, this only works on your allies though
